# jshint cannot determine if it is a variable or function

Tags: javascript, jshint, lint

​I have this code

```
var x = 5;
x("aaaa");
```

It still passes even though `x` is not a function. It is not clear what `x` is in runtime?

Comment: It is quite difficult to know whether an identifier exists or what type it is in Javascript, given the possibilities of overlapping scopes and dynamic shenanigans with `window` .

Comment: If you want stricter type checking, look at TypeScript. That would have given you an error ("Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature").